# cordova dbcopy plugin after opening database shows database is empty

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have database name test.db i am trying to import this db file into ionic application.after successfully copying db file into application i am opening database and trying to access tables from database but it showing no tables in database.but database file is not empty when it opens in database file format. why is this db file showing empty after opening into application?

```
var app = angular.module('Traceability', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'restangular'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite, $database, Restangular) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

            // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
            // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
            // a much nicer keyboard experience.
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

        ////database initialization when app is loading
        if (window.cordova) {
            window.plugins.sqlDB.copy("test.db", "default",
                function(success) {
                    console.log(success)
                    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
                        name: "test.db",
                        iosDatabaseLocation: "default"
                    });
                    if (db) {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            var query = "SELECT *FROM sqlite_master";
                            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query)
                                .then(function(data) {
                                    console.log(data)
                                });
                        }, 5000);
                    }
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log(error)
                });
        } else {
            console.log("error")
        };




    });
})
```

Comment: can you share some of your codes, controller and view

Comment: i shared my code